# How can you explicitly mark @Input() properties as readonly in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Inputs are the main source of communication between components in Angular, but they are mutable by default which can lead to unwanted behavior throughout the application. This can easily slip through a code review (which I am responsible for) and end up in the production codebase.

Given the following code:

```js
export class UserListComponent {
  @Input() users: User[] = [];

  filterLocally(filter: string): void {
    this.users = this.users.filter((u) => u.name === filter);
  }
}
```

Any array passed on from the parent component to the `users` input has the risk of being changed. Let's say that this array originated from a cache which is also being used in different pages throughout the application. After applying a filter, this data would become modified and all those pages would receive invalid data. I know that this is theoretically allowed, but this is (in my opinion) such a bad pattern that we should be able to block this, especially when you're working in a team with a lot of junior developers.

Is there a way to explicitly mark an @Input() as readonly? I've tried the following:

```js
export class UserListComponent {
  @Input() readonly users: User[] = []; // <-- added the readonly keyword -|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|

  filterLocally(filter: string): void {
    this.users = this.users.filter((u) => u.name === filter);
  }
}
```

Which will trigger the following error at code/build time which is perfect as it forces you to create a local copy of the variable:

[image: Error in controller]

But it also blocks you from initially passing data to this component which kind of destroys the purpose:

[image: Error in template]

Marking the input as such also does not work, because this can easily be circumvented in the controller:

```js
@Input() users: Readonly<User[]> = [];
```

So far I haven't found a way to properly block this. Right now I'd even settle for a way to simply disable the rule inside .html files, but I cannot figure out a way to do this. A simple find & replace from `@Input() ...` to `@Input() readonly ...` in our project yielded 200+ errors, so being able to mark the inputs as readonly would be a tremendous help for us.

Comment: Well you can't have both. If you want the input to be readonly, you have to pass it a readonly variable. (or disable the strict flag).

Comment: It _can't_ be read-only. Angular assigns that property after the component is created (between `constructor` and `ngOnInit`) so they have to be public and writable.

Comment: using @input you can pass values from parent to child component. In child component you received values from parent to "users" array. Then you filter out that this.users array and assign to result it again, it will not effect to your cache area data source or anything unless you set it to cache area data source.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a service or some sort of a cache to set the value of `users` internally, you should not be relying on `@Input`s at all to pass data between components. The idea of a property marked as an `@Input` is to react to changes from its parent. I would suggest using a service as a single source of truth for the whole application and then querying it inside all the components that need that data.

Comment: if you still want to read user list as input, then create a deepcopy of it and then use.